# Integrating SCORM eLearning into a .NET app - where should I start?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, scorm

My colleagues and I are keen to embed SCORM compliant eLearning into our .NET/SQLServer web application.

We've been provided with a number of eLearning resources that have been authored as "SCORM compliant" and although I can see that it might be easy to host these packages by just uploading them to our server I was wondering if I should take the extra leap and make the application fully compliant.

Are there any tools, classes or examples (preferably free) available that might help me achieve this?

My understanding of the situation is that I need to:

- Provide an "installation" tool so that we can install/manage these packages on the system.
- Link the packages to our database to enable us to track progress etc...
- Anything else?

This system already requires users to create an account/profile so I'm guessing we could link their eLearning to their account.

Many thanks for your time,

Answer (score 3):

To get started learning about how to implement SCORM, check out [SCORM Explained](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/).

There are also two tools there that can add the ability to import, track and deliver SCORM conformant content to your application. The [SCORM Engine](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-engine/) and [SCORM Cloud](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud/develop-a-scorm-cloud-app/) were both designed to do just that, but they are not free.